# Trying to figure out if string has equal amounts of X and O with loop

Tags: javascript

```
 function ExOh(str) { 
   sumsofarx=0;
   sumsofary=0;
       for(var i=0; i<str.length;i++)
         if(str(i)==x){
          sumsofarx++;

            }
if(str(i)==y){
 sumsofary++;

 }
     if(sumsofarx % sumsofary===0){
     return true;
 }
 else{
     return false;
 }



 };
  console.log(ExOh("xo"));
```

I'm thinking my syntax may be off here I'm trying to figure out if x and o are read when looped if they are if there is an even amount of Xs and Os return true if there isnt return false what did i mess up here I dont really want to know easier ways to write my code(even though I wouldnt mind and any criticism is appreciated :) ) but i want to know what i need to do to make my code work im thinking my code has syntax errors at the if sections thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace `str(i)` with `str[i]`.

Comment: Not sure how new you are to coding, but proper indentation and use of curley braces makes code much more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to access a character at specific index inside of a string, you have to use the square brackets or the method .charAt(index):

`str(i)` should be `str[i]` or `str.charAt(i)`

then, in this instruction:

```
if(str(i)==x)
```

you are trying to compare the character at index `i` with `x`, but, what is `x`?

Your corrected code should be like:

```
function ExOh(str) { 
    sumsofarx = 0;
    sumsofary = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] === 'x') {
            sumsofarx++;
        }
        if (str[i] === 'o') {
            sumsofary++;
        }
    }
    if (sumsofarx === sumsofary) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is the modulo necesarry couldnt i achieve the same result with if(sumsofarx === sumsofary)?

Comment: Yes the modulus is not necessary and also incorrect. I modified the code.

Comment: Even shorter for returning true or false: return (sumsofarx === sumsofary);

Comment: I would add an "else" before the second "if" in order to make the code more efficient. If str[i] == 'x', it won't be also equal to 'o' ;-)